# LeNet for Convolution network?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network

I keep seeing LeNet used to referring to a convolution network? I am wondering why LeNet is called LeNet? Is it the abbreviation of anything? Is there a difference between LeNet and convolutional neural network? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[LeNet](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/) is a family (LeNet-1, LeNet-4, LeNet-5) of convolutional neural network designed by Yann LeCun et al. The name is a play on his name and the French language, where "le" means "the", hence LeNet means "the network". I believe it was originally devised to recognize handwritten numbers on checks (cheques). LeNet is only one early instance of a convolutional neural network; many others exist today.